# jquery autocomplete custom data and display

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, custom-data-attribute

I am working on the jquery autocomplete custom data and display.  I can't figure out how to get the returned data to show up as two lines for each item.  The label and value and the autocomplete are all working but formatting the data is where I need help.  I've checked in firefox and the item.vcCCQualtsCustomTitle has data.  when I try to use the .data the item.desc doesn't appear to be wired up correctly because it doesn't show the data (that I mapped in the success)

Here is the code

```
$(function () {
$(".cClassID").click(function () {//fires off when you click on the textbox, that the entire textbox gets selected so you don't have to backspace stuff out
    $(this).focus();
    $(this).select();
});
$(".cClassID").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/GeneralUserControls/wsClassIndex.aspx/_ClassIndexSearch_TestOnly",
            data: "{ 'ClassIndex': '" + request.term + "' }",//Parm name and what is in the textbox passed in
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.ClassTitle, //map properties used in class returned by JSON to what autocomplete wants
                        value: item.tblClassIndexID,
                        desc: item.vcCCQualtsCustomTitle
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select://fires off when you make a selection
        function (event, ui) {
            //$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucClassIndex_txtClassIndex").val(ui.item.label);
            //$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucClassIndex_hfClassIndexID").val(ui.item.value);
            $("[id$=txtClassIndex]").val(ui.item.label);
            $("[id$=hfClassIndexID]").val(ui.item.value);
            $("#project-description").html(ui.item.desc);
            //AppChanged(ui.item.value);//if JaxIt is not there..there is no error.. it just never runs

            return false;
        },
    focus: function (event, ui) {//what populates the drop down
        //$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucClassIndex_txtClassIndex").val(ui.item.label);
        //$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucClassIndex_hfClassIndexID").val(ui.item.value);
        $("[id$=txtClassIndex]").val(ui.item.label);
        $("[id$=hfClassIndexID]").val(ui.item.value);

        return false;
    },
}).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $('<li></li>')
        .data('item.autocomplete', item)
        .append(item.name + item.desc)
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

});

I don't know if I need the $("#project-description").html(ui.item.desc); in the select:.  I saw it in one of the many examples I've been through so it's left in there.  Any help on how to get the .data to work would be great.

thanks
Shannon

The data portion should look something like this

```
}).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $('<li>')
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.label + "<br/>" + item.desc + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Comment: have it figured out... in the data portion.. it needs to read .data('ui-autocomplete') instead of just autocomplete.  Also the append section needs to be wrapped in <a> tags.. I've edited the above code to show it

Comment: This dumbs it down to caveman level: https://github.com/FREE-FROM-CMS/AutoComplete